# I want review from my google business account

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, google-my-business-api, google-my-business

I am using google API php client and getting below error. This code is working fine before a week. Current its not working and passing error. may be some deprecated by google after that its not working. Please help me out as soon as possible because its affect on live product and can't able to show review.

```
$http = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'verify' => false
]);
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setHttpClient($http);
$client->setApplicationName('Magic Minds WEB');
$client->setAuthConfigFile(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
$client->setRedirectUri(redirectUri);
$client->setScopes("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage");
$client->setAccessType("offline");
$client->setApprovalPrompt("force");

$mybusinessService = new Google_Service_MyBusiness($client);

$credentialsPath = tokenJson;

// Load previously authorized credentials from a file.

$accessToken = (array)json_decode(file_get_contents($credentialsPath));

$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

// Refresh the token if it's expired.

if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {

$client->refreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());

file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));

}

// For testing purposes, selects the very first account in the accounts array

$accounts = $mybusinessService->accounts;

// echo "<pre>";
//print_r($accounts);

$accountsList = $accounts->listAccounts()->getAccounts();
print_r($accountsList);
$account = $accountsList[2];

// For testing purposes, selects the very first location in the locations array

$locations = $mybusinessService->accounts_locations;

$locationsList = $locations->listAccountsLocations($account->name)->getLocations();

$location = $locationsList[0];

// Lists all reviews for the specified location

$reviews = $mybusinessService->accounts_locations_reviews;

$listReviewsResponse = $reviews->listAccountsLocationsReviews($location->name);

$reviewsList = $listReviewsResponse->getReviews();
```

Getting below error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Google\Service\Exception: { "error": { "code": 400, "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.", "errors": [ { "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.", "domain": "global", "reason": "badRequest" } ], "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT", "details": [ { "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.mybusiness.v4.ValidationError", "errorDetails": [ { "message": "This API will soon be deprecated. Please migrate all the usages to My Business Account Management API - https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/accountmanagement/rest" } ] } ] } } in /var/www/html/magicmind/magicmindsweb/backend/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Http/REST.php:128 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/magicmind/magicmindsweb/backend/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Http/REST.php(103): Google\Http\REST::decodeHttpResponse() #1 [internal function]:

efforts will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Google is shutting down that api as stated in the error message. They have stated

> Starting April 30, 2022, the following four API methods will return errors with increasing frequency, ramping up to 100% shut down within 30 days.

As today is June 07, 2022 You are past the 30 day grace period. So the error message you are getting is the result of that.

> This API will soon be deprecated. Please migrate all the usages to My Business Account Management API - [https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/accountmanagement/rest"](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/accountmanagement/rest%22)

I would just start to migrate to the new api as they have directed, This is not something you can fix as that API no longer exists.

See [accounts management api](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/accountmanagement/rest/v1/accounts)

Comment: I'm having the same problem but the main issue is that a replace for the reviews api doesn't seem to exist in the new service, at least as far as I can see.
The documentation only lists the v4.9 calls (that no longer work)

Comment: Google often shuts things down without supplying an alterative.   Leaving us to wonder why